# KML To Automobile GPS

Tags: gps, kml

I've created a bunch of Placemarks and have them in a kml file.
Is there a way to get this into the GPS of a car?

Comment: depends on year and model of the car. https://www.google.ca/maps/sendtocar?source=tldsi&hl=en

Comment: If you're savvy enough, you might be able to hack it in there.  I know an older GPS unit of mine used map tile packages (like ESRI .tpk) for their updates.  It could be possible that you get a hold of and modify one to 'update' your GPS.  Could possibly be more effort than it is worth though.